# Notepad++ REGEX: Keep only last 2 substrings in string separated by dots

Tags: notepad++, regex

Strings representing file names with substrings of characters separated by "." Each string has a varying number of substrings, each of which can be any text, except the last one, which is the file extension. I want to keep only the last substring S1 and the file extension; e.g.:

What I have:

```
S4.S3.S2.S1.txt
S2.S1.txt
S3.S2.S1.txt
S1.txt
```

What I want:

```
S1.txt
S1.txt
S1.txt
S1.txt
```

where `S1`, `S2`, `S3`, … can be anything (letters, numbers, parens, embedded hyphens) and different in each line, while the last substring (txt in this example) is always the same. I am trying to construct a REGEX for this and failing miserably. Can anyone suggest a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Find what: `^.*[^\w](\w+\.\w+)$`
Replace with: `\1`

Explanation:

```
`^` - start of line
`.*` - one or zero characters
`[^\w]` - one character which is not a word (alphanumeric or underscore)
`(` - start of group 1
`\w+` - one or more word characters
`\.` - the character `.` escaped
`\w+` - one or more word characters
`)` - end of group 1
`$` -  end of line
```

Comment: Brilliant! I was way off. That works great, except I didn't realize when I posted that some of my substrings contain hypens which I want to keep. Is that a simple edit to the regex?

Comment: Untested: `^.*[^\w-]([\w-]+\.[\w-]+)$`

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^.*?(?=[^.]+\.[^.]+\.[^.]+$)`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^                   # beginning of line
    .*?             # 0 or more any character but newline
    (?=             # positive lookahead, make sure we have after:
        [^.]+           # 1 or more non dot
        \.              # 1 dot
        [^.]+           # 1 or more non dot
        \.              # 1 dot
        [^.]+           # 1 or more non dot
      $                 # end of line
    )               # end lookahead
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]